# System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.' Error

Tags: vb.net

Please help. I have a  piece of code that's already working in other parks of my program, however fails to work when accessed by a certain form so i can't see there can be an error with it. Its an information storage project using text files. A screenshot of the exact code and the error:

[image]

I expected it to change the label text to the contents of the text file its trying to read.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: And what is the value of `zoot1s`? Because the exception message is pretty clear and there aren't any bad characters in `c.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there must be one or more illegal characters coming from your "zoots1.txt" file!

Build the filename and see what it looks like:

```
Dim zoot1s As String
zoot1s = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("zoot1s.txt")
Dim fileName As String
fileName = zoot1s + "c.txt"
MessageBox.Show(fileName)

Dim ClassStrain As String
ClassStrain = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName)
TempLabel3.Text = ClassStrain
Timer1.Start()
```

**--- EDIT --**

*My bad. I Found the issue to be that there is a skip in text where it goes to a new line. As if i had added vbNewline to it. Is there any way to edit the text file and take away the last character so there isnt a new line.*

Use the `Trim()` function to get rid of white space.   Also use `Path.Combine()` to make sure the path is correctly separated from the filename with the correct number of backslashes:

```
zoot1s = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("zoot1s.txt").Trim()
Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(zoot1s, "c.txt")
```

Comment: But that wouldn’t make sense, why would it work in one part of the program and not the other?

Comment: Despite not making sense, that's the error you're getting.  What is the output?

Comment: My bad. I Found the issue to be that there is a skip in text where it goes to a new line. As if i had added vbNewline to it.  Is there any way to edit the text file and take away the last character so there isnt a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed the most important thing, which is the whole specific path of your file that will be reading data from, specifically after the ReadAllText() method, so instead of this line:

zoom1s=My.computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText('zoot1s.txt")

You should edit it like this:

```
zoom1s=My.computer.FileSystem.ReadAllTex(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & \zoot1s.txt")
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

^_^